# How to choose option from DropDownList when select not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this simple `DropDownList`:

```
<select id="cmp_pp" name="cmp[val_id]" class="jcf-hidden"><option value="false" selected="selected">No</option>
<option value="true">Yes</option></select>
```

As you can see this `DropDownList` contains only 2 options: `Yes` or `No`.

And i try to select option this way:

```
val dropDownList = 
new Select(
driver.findElement(By.cssselector("select[id=cmp_pp]")))
```

And i try all the following:

```
dropDownList.selectByVisibleText("Yes")
dropDownList.selectByIndex(1)
dropDownList..selectByValue("true")
```

And none of them works.

I found another way to change this `DropDownList`:

Open the `DropDownList` by `click` and then loop over all the `options` and `click` on the desire `option` that i want but my question is if there is another elegant way to do that ? (maybe java script ?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by using sendkeys? if select command does not works then good to use sendkeys.

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.cmp_pp")).sendKeys("Yes");
```

I hope element is not in frame and tried with required waits, other locators as well instead of css.

Comment: Then try directly click on required option. like //option[@value='true']